# If you are using @EnableWebMvc annotation, why must the Dto that @RequestBody calls be annotated with @NoArgsConstructor?

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations

what is a reason about `Dto` that used by `@RequestBody` annotation at `RestController` must have `@NoArgsConstructor` when use `@EnableWebMvc` in project?

If project don't have `@EnableWebMvc`, it's easy to map automatically with `@Getter` Annotation without `@NoArgsConstructor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using @EnableWebMvc, it means that you are giving Spring the responsibility of doing what is necessary. @EnableWebMvc ensures that Spring takes control of a necessary No-Argument Constructor from the user with a pre-defined annotation @NoArgsConstructor.

It also avoids unnecessary boiler-plate code that the developer would have to write.